# VSCode highlights import of files with .ts and .tsx extensions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image: example of import highlight]

I'm new to TypeScript. The code works fine, but VSCode keeps highlighting import with .ts and .tsx extensions. If I remove the extension from the import, VSCode stops complaining, but the code does not compile.

It is a react based project. For compiling I use WebPack, specifically ts-loader for .ts and .tsx extensions.

VSCode identifies correctly that this is a TypeScript React file, and TypeScript version 4.0.2
[image: TypeScript React 4.0.2]

Comment: Importing with an explicit typescript extension (`.ts` or `.tsx`) is an error. Either import without an extension or use `.js` or `.jsx` and the compiler will figure it out. For webpack: `resolve: {extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! My bad. Needed to add

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
```

to webpack config